# How can I detect which storage space on Android, in which an image exists

Tags: android, storage, android-sdcard, mediastore

I am building something like an image gallery app. But when I use the code below to retrieve the images on an Android device, I don't seem to know if the image exists in the device's primary external storage (Internal memory) or secondary external storage (SD card). How would I distinguish the two ?

### My code below

```
// root_extra was gotten from the starter of this activity. It can either be MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI or MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI based on whichever storage location user wants to access by clicking either of two buttons available in the starter activity (Phone storage and SD card)
     String root_extra = getIntent().getStringExtra(STORAGE_ACCESS_ROOT);
            Uri storageUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            if (root_extra != null) {
                storageUri = root_extra.equals(EXTERNAL) ? MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                        : MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
    
            String[] projection = {
                    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
            Cursor imgCursor = getApplicationContext()
                    .getContentResolver()
                    .query(storageUri, projection, null, null, null);
    
            int bucketId = imgCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
            int imgSize = imgCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE);
            int name = imgCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int bucketName
                    = imgCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
    
            List<String> dirName = new ArrayList<>();
            while (imgCursor.moveToNext()) {
                long id = imgCursor.getLong(bucketId);
                int size = imgCursor.getInt(imgSize);
                String fileName = imgCursor.getString(name);
                String folderName = imgCursor.getString(bucketName);
    
                Uri contentUri
                        = ContentUris.withAppendedId(storageUri, id);
                Image currentImage = new Image(contentUri, size, fileName, folderName);
    
                int directoryIndex = linearSearch(dirName, folderName);
                // if search result (directoryIndex) passes this test, then it means that there is
                // no such directory in list of directory names
                if (directoryIndex < 0) {
                    imageDirectoryList.add(new ArrayList<>());
                    dirName.add(folderName);
                    directoryIndex = linearSearch(dirName, folderName);
                    if (directoryIndex >= 0)
                        imageDirectoryList.get(directoryIndex).add(currentImage);
                } else {
                    imageDirectoryList.get(directoryIndex).add(currentImage);
                }
            }
    
            imgCursor.close();
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                doViewUpdate();
            });
```

I was using `MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` to access the primary external storage (or Internal memory as I referred to it as), but it doesn't work.

Comment: `can only have one memory(I` It is unclear what you consider to be memory.

Comment: `to access the images that exist on the device, ` There exist no images on an emulator just out of the box. Then you put them there or took pictures with a Camera app.

Comment: `with both Internal memory and external SD card, I get only the images that exist on the SD card. ` No. I have never seen a device where the media store would act like that.

Comment: Post your code. We will not follow links.

Comment: @blackapps, am so sorry, I forgot to upload my code. I'll do that in a moment.

Comment: @blackapps check it out now. I uploaded the code

Comment: Already on the first line i have no idea what the value would be of root_extra. And then i stopped.